# Blender Uv Editor проблемы с текстурами

Tags: файлы

Есть ли способ добавить текстуру должным образом к модифицированному объекту? Когда я добавляю текстуру к обычьному объект, например на одну из сторон куба работает идеально, но когда я добавить к модифицированному объекта выглядит так screenshot 1.
Например у меня есть одна сторона стены дома, когда я добавить текстуру и открытый редактор это выглядит как screen 1, я попытался сделать некоторые манипуляции в vector mapping , но это выглядит плохо screenshot 2.

screen 1:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

screen 2:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: screen 1 http://imgur.com/a/kp5VV

Comment: screenshot 2  http://imgur.com/a/g1Ctq